# Insert login and registration data not show in SQL Server database table Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, database

I'm making a tool using Visual Studio 2019. When I tried to click registration button and there's no errors. But when I open the database and refresh the table, there's no data in the data table.

Any support for this issue much appreciated. Thank you.

```
private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //connection string
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\ImageSteganography_2\ImageSteganography\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        // Connection open here   
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        if (repeatPassBox.Text != string.Empty || passBox.Text != string.Empty || contactBox.Text != string.Empty || emailBox.Text != string.Empty || userBox.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            //Email Address
            if (validate_email.IsMatch(emailBox.Text) != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email Address!", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                emailBox.Focus();
            }
            // Contacts
            else if (validate_contact.IsMatch(contactBox.Text) != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Contact accept numbers only (10 digit).", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                contactBox.Focus();
            }
            // Password
            else if (validate_password.IsMatch(passBox.Text) != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password must be atleast 8 to 15 characters. It should contain at least one Upper case and numbers.", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                passBox.Focus();
            }
            // Repeat Password
            else if (passBox.Text != repeatPassBox.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter both password same ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } 
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where username='" + userBox.Text + "'", conn);
                
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Username already exists - please try another ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Registration values (@username, @email, @contact, @password, @repeatPassword)", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", userBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", emailBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("contact", contactBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", passBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("repeatPassword", repeatPassBox.Text);
                    

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Login values(@username,@password)", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", userBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", passBox.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Register successful. Please login now.", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Hide();
                    LOGIN f1 = new LOGIN();
                    f1.ShowDialog();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All input fields cannot be blank.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! It may seem that your settings are not correct, it's not persisting data. Click on your database in the solution explorer and look at its properties. The property "Copy to output directory" should be set to "copy if newer". On another note, I would do your validation first, you're creating objects you may not use; specifically creating a connection and command. Also don't store passwords ever, you need to hash + salt them and store those in the db... Use parameters *everywhere* don't pick when to use them. Finally use the `Add` method and not `AddWithValue`....

Comment: It will infer the datatype and could be wrong, you should be specifying the datatype, length etc. for the parameter you're adding.

Comment: Further reading, there's other issues. You're trying to insert into a table `Registration`, but you're not executing that command and then you're trying to insert into the `Login` table after... Also your not targeting your parameters correctly in your `AddWithValue`, should be `@username`, `@email` etc... `and there's no errors.` I would have to disagree with this statement as there clearly should be.

Comment: The "8 to 15" password validation scares me. The NIST standard says it's better not to have an upper limit on password size, but if you absolutely must that limit **must** be at least 64 characters. Also, it's very much **not okay to insert the password without first salting and hashing**. This is one of those things that's _too important to do wrong even for practice/learning/proof-of-concept projects._ Finally, you never actually run the query for the registration table.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix a **LOT** of small issues in the original, some not-so-small, and should run faster as a bonus. That said, it's also a lot of code typed directly into the reply window, so it likely has a bug or five of its own still to work out:

```
private (string, Control) CheckRegistrationData()
{
    //Email Address
    if (emailBox.Text == "" || validate_email.IsMatch(emailBox.Text) != true)
    {
        return ("Invalid Email Address!", emailBox);
    }
    
    //Contacts
    if (contactBox.Text == "" || validate_contact.IsMatch(contactBox.Text) != true)
    {
        return ("Contact accept numbers only (10 digit).", contactBox);
    }

    // Password
    if (passBox.Text == "" || validate_password.IsMatch(passBox.Text) != true)
    {
        return ("Password must be atleast 8 to 15 characters. It should contain at least one Upper case and numbers.");
    }

    //Repeat Password
    if (repeatPassBox.Text == "" || passBox.Text != repeatPassBox.Text)
    {
        return ("Please enter both password same ", repeatPassBox);
    }
     
    return ("", null);
}

private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var validationResult = CheckRegistrationData();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationResult.Item1))
     {
         MessageBox.Show(validationResult.Item1, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         if (validationResult.Item2 is Control)
         {
             valiadtionResult.Item2.Focus();
         }
         return;
     }
     
     // VALIDATION COMPLETE

     string SQL = @"
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Login WHERE Username= @username )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Username Already exist',16,1);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Registration (Username, Email, Contact, PasswordHash)
    VALUES (@username,@email,@contact,@passwordHash);
    INSERT INTO Login (UserName, PasswordHash) VALUES (@username,@passwordHash);
END
";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\ImageSteganography_2\ImageSteganography\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn))
    {   //Much better to replace AddWithValue() with Add() and provide explicit type information about the database columns.     
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contactBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwordHash", BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(passBox.Text)); //Based on BCrypt.Net Nuget package

        try 
        {                     
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex) when (ex.Errors[0].Class == 16)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username Already exist please try another ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            return; 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error trying to create registration: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            return;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Register successful. Please login now.", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.Hide();
    var f1 = new LOGIN();
    f1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: CoehoornSo the op could have just added a ";" to first query and then added a cmd += to second.  Like a stacked query.

Comment: @duerzd696 Sort of. But this also adds the check for the existing record, properly closes the connection, properly hashes the password, etc.

Comment: Yes usings are way better, you wont ever have to worry about closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the command parameters incorrectly:
Try something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = userBox.Text;
```

Also, use two Executenonquerys one for registration and other for other table.

Comment: This is better, but AddWithValue() will still work (it just has performance issues when the types are inferred poorly). The problem is they never call ExecuteNonQuery() for the first cmd.

Comment: I was also wondering if the op could just add a ";" to the first query and add the "@" to the parameters?

Comment: @duerzd696 the connection is opened right after the connection instance is created, just a few lines down.

Comment: If I downvote, I leave an explanation as to why. It happens, something we can't control. My suggestion is to review your answer and see if it can be improved with any further details and or suggestions.

Comment: @trevorDid you ever try just adding the ";" like I mentioned?  I will put that on my list of things to try - but just curious now.